# select only men or women fields - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a website that someone can choose if they want to see man or woman.

I have user, gender_preference and gender row.

```
SELECT gender_preference FROM users where user = 'b' LIMIT 1;
variable $g

SELECT user FROM users where gender = $g  LIMIT 20;
```

first I select the gender preference from one user, than I can select all users that are relevant.

How can I do the same thing using just one select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Select * from users where gender in (select gender_preference from users where user = $g)
```

You can have the in query to select the gender for the user and outer query to give users.

Comment: Does this count as one select?

Comment: You can use `=` instead `IN` cause nested query must return one row

Comment: @Artem, just in case if the user has both as gender preference.

Comment: @TZHX, yes indeed it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the `gender_preference` column only for filtering if that's whay you are getting as input from end user.

```
SELECT `user` FROM `users`
where gender_preference = 'man` LIMIT 20;
```

(OR)

If you really want to combine both your query then combine the `WHERE` conditions like below but that's almost unnecessary as you will end up getting record for `user b`

```
SELECT `user`
FROM `users`
where gender_preference = gender
and   user = 'b'
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: @TZHX, and why not? What OP trying to do is pretty unnecessary

Comment: In that the results you are getting, don't match what the OP wants, and you're selecting based on entirely the wrong column.

Comment: And whether what the OP is doing is unnecessary is up to them to state. If the choice is made every time a search is made, maybe. If it's stored on the user object and reused it makes more sense to query it as a variable, subselect or join.

Comment: @TZHX, well may be but I certainly don't agree with you. That would be a wired thing to do using a variable when both the columns belong to same table and in such case don't see why the suggested answer is wrong.

Comment: It's wrong in that it simply doesn't meet the specification. As I said in my first comment. It does not answer the question. But whatever.